# SSRS Expressions Iif

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, expression, iif

I have to write an IIf or Switch 
in SSRS expressions 
which satisfy the below condition

If the field value is positive it should display "Dr" next to the value
If the field value is negavtive it should display "Cr" next to the value 
If the value is 0 then no value should be displayed in the field

for example a value of -100 should be displayed as ' 100 Cr ' (excluding quotations)
and a value of 100 should be displayed as  ' 100 Dr ' 
and a value of 0 should be displayed as " " (ie blank)

i am new at this

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about presentation rather than data. Accordingly I wouldn't use an `IIF` function for the `Value` expression, I would use the `Format` property. Leave the `Value` just being the field and use a format like: `#,##0 Dr;-#,##0 Cr;`

The first part of the format is the part that displays positive numbers, the second part displays negative numbers and the last part displays zero value.